# Does Laravel Eloquent work with callbacks?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, closures

I want to get the related user details filtered by time. My query is as follows;

```
    $employer = $user->organizations->where('status', true)
        ->where('start_date', '<=', date("Y-m-d"))
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query
                ->where('end_date', '>=', date("Y-m-d"))
                ->orWhereNull('end_date');
        });
```

I am getting results without the callback but when I introduce the callback to filter out data by the end date, I get error `"explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given"`.

How should this be refactored to get organization(s) where either the end date is null or is in the future?

Comment: I think you forgot to get the data. If this code snippet is correct, the `$employer` variable is a Builder class, not a Collection. Try to use `->get()`.

Comment: By the way, `$user->organizations` is `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`. In this case, you are not searching in database. If you want to search in the database (for better performance), use `$user->organizations()` method, instead of property.

Answer (score 2):

You should **return** closure function

try this:

```
$employer = $user->organizations->where('status', true)
    ->where('start_date', '<=', date("Y-m-d")->toDateTimeString())
    ->where(function ($query) {
        return $query
            ->where('end_date', '>=', date("Y-m-d")->toDateTimeString())
            ->orWhereNull('end_date');
    });
```

Comment: you should convert date to string, Object given

Answer (score 0):

As per [Levente Otta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7991098/levente-otta) comments above, I refactored the code to the following;

```
        $employer = $user->organizations()->where('organization_user.status', true)
        ->where('organization_user.start_date', '<=', date("Y-m-d"))
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query
                ->where('organization_user.end_date', '>=', date("Y-m-d"))
                ->orWhereNull('organization_user.end_date');
        })->get();
```